# Dynamically choose equality operator in Perl

Tags: perl, comparison, operators

I have a list of values of mixed types (strings and numbers):

```
my @list = (123, 'foo', 34.5, 'bar', '67baz');
```

For each item on that list, I need to compare against an input of equally random type (string or number) in order to do something:

```
my $input = 345;
foreach my $elem (@list) {
    if ($input == $elem) {
        # do something
    } else {
        # do something else
    }
}
```

The comparison (`==`) will work fine when both operands are of the same type (numbers in this case), but will raise a warning and/or produce a wrong result when the types are a mismatch (for this code snippet, it could be string vs. number, or both could be strings, thus requiring the use of `eq` instead).

I would like to get some input on your preferred ways of solving this comparison problem. Or if maybe there is a module that dynamically chooses (and performs) the right type of comparison given the type of operands.

I'm aware of methods such as using `looks_like_number()` from `Scalar::Util` to check what type of value you're working with, but thought maybe there's a better approach to figure out how to do comparisons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need `345` to match `345.0` and `3.45e2`? If not then you should just use `eq` all the time.

Answer (score 3):

In many languages, the type of the operands determine the operation. In Perl, the operator determines the operation and the operands will be coerced into the proper type. As such, Perl doesn't consider four stored as a string different than four stored as a integer; they're both four. And if you have code that tries to figure out if a scalar is a number or a string, you have buggy code<sup>[1]</sup>.

If you insist, then you'll need to come up with a definition of what *you* consider to be a number as opposed to a string. If you choose "it's a number if Perl can use it as a number, and string otherwise", then `looks_like_number` will indeed to the trick. You could also choose to decide based on how the value is stored in the scalar, but then you have to decide what to do when a scalar has both a integer and a string within<sup>[2]</sup>.

On the other hand, if you are trying to write generic code, then you could have your function accept a compare function (like `sort` does).

```
sub find(&@) {
   my $cb = shift;
   for (@_) {
      return 1 if $cb->();
   }

   return 0;
}


if (find { $_ == $num_to_find } @nums) {
   print("Found $num_to_find\n");
} else {
   print("Didn't find $num_to_find\n");
}

find { $_ eq $string_to_find } @strings

find { $_->year == $year_to_find } @date_time_objects;
```

---

1. That's why the smartmatch operator is considered buggy and needs to be changed before it stops being experimental.
2. `perl -le'open(my $fh, "<", "non-existent"); print 0+$!; print "".$!;'`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally), which imports an `ncmp` operator that does a 'Natural' comparison.

To check for equality you could do this

```
use Sort::Naturally;
if ( ncmp( $lval, $rval ) == 0 ) { ... }
```

Here's some examples of how `ncmp` treats some pairs.

```
ncmp(1, '1')   ==  0
ncmp('a', 'a') ==  0
ncmp('a', 'b') == -1
ncmp('a', 'A') == -1
ncmp(2, 1)     ==  1
ncmp(1, 'a')   == -1
ncmp('a', 1)   ==  1
```

Basically...

`0` is equality
`1` means `lval` is less-that `rval`
`-1` means `lval` is greater-than `rval`

Answer (score 0):

use perl [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) string , which is kind of a mini-perl program within your program ( you can do this easily in scripting languages , Perl eval is besides much more powerful than everything else around , yet with great power comes great responsibility ... ) :

```
    # get the var guiding the dynamic operator
    my $issues_order_by_attribute= $ENV{ 'issues_order_by_attribute' } || 'prio' ;
    my $operator = '<=>' ;   # initialize a default operator
    # use Scalar::Util looks_like_number method to decide for operator 
    $operator = 'cmp'  unless ( looks_like_number( $issues_order_by_attribute ) ) ;
    # use eval string within the code to interpolate the operator
    # to sort the hash ref of hash refs by the set attribute to order by
    foreach my $issue_id (
        eval 'sort {      ' .
            '$hsr2->{$a}->{ $issues_order_by_attribute }' . $operator . '$hsr2->{$b}->{ $issues_order_by_attribute }' .
            '} keys (%$hsr2)' )  {
        # Action !!! 
        my $row = $hsr2->{ $issue_id } ;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

The [smartmatch operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) would let you write

```
no if $] >= 5.018, warnings => qw( experimental::smartmatch );

my $input = 123;  # also works with 34.5, 'foo', etc.
foreach my $elem (@list) {
    if ($elem ~~ $input) {
        # do something
    } else {
        # do something else
    }
}
```

The idea was taken from Perl 6, and was implemented in 5.10. Since Perl 5.18, there have been discussions about how to evolve the feature to better fit Perl 5, so the interface has been downgraded to "experimental" status pending changes.

Comment: That's rather misleading. They're not trying to evolve it into something better; it's buggy and they're trying to fix it. Worse, you are specifically using it for the behaviour that needs to be fixed. It will NOT leave experimental status without first breaking your code.